# How to import sql dump file in MySQLContainer in JUnit test containers

Tags: java, mysql, docker, junit, testcontainers

I have a test container for Mysql and I need to import the dump file after the container started. I've tried two options below.

```
public class AbstractTest {

    public static MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:5.7");

    static {
        mySQLContainer
            .withDatabaseName("myDatabase")
            .withCopyFileToContainer(
                MountableFile.forClasspathResource("init.sql", 0744),
                "init.sql")
            .withUsername("root")
            .withPassword("root")
            .start();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @SneakyThrows
    public void init() {
       option 1 // mySQLContainer.execInContainer("mysql -u root -proot myDatabase < init.sql");
       option 2 // mySQLContainer.execInContainer("mysql", "-u", "root", "-proot", "myDatabase", "<", "init.sql");
    }
   ////
}
```

and still no success - it looks like mysql can't parse my command properly cause I get next as an answer:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.35, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
////.....
```

If use next command

```
  option 2 // mySQLContainer.execInContainer("mysql", "-u", "root", "-proot");
```

it works fine, but this is not what I wanted

`mysql -u root -proot mydatabase < init.sql` command works fine if I just connect to the container via bash from cli.

So my question - how to import SQL dump file in MySQLContainer in JUnit test containers by executing the command in image?

UPDATE:
I figured out that there is some thing wrong with parsing of "<" sign.
So, basically this works fine from CLI:

```
docker exec -i  mycontainer mysql -uroot -proot myDatabase < init.sql
```

But this is not working from Java:

```
mySQLContainer.execInContainer("mysql","-uroot","-proot","myDatabase","<","init.sql");
```

Comment: Your test infrastructure should have some sort of seed-data system; can you use that instead?  In general once the database is up, you can just connect to it without caring that it's in a container.  (You should not normally need `docker exec`, especially in code.)  Also consider using an in-process database like H2 or SQLite for tests, which won't require an external tool or administrator-level permissions to run.

Comment: @DavidMaze The thing is that in my project migrations and db population were initially put in different project (wrong architecture), so I did not want to use something like Flyway to load data in test container, cause it may confuse people why the Flyway (or any other migration lib) is used in project, when all migrations are in different project. I thought applying sgl dump with using of mysql commands directly to container by the means of the test containers makes sense. But unfortunately they don't fully support all commands.

Comment: I do believe `execInContainer("sh", "-c", "'mysql -uroot -proot myDatabase < init.sql'")` should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL can load a dump file automatically if you put it at a special path.

From the docs of the [MySQL Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql):

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
> the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
> configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
> extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
> order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL
> dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed
> data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
> by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

So the easiest is to copy the file there with something like:

```
.withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("init.sql"), "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql")
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you, Олег :)

Comment: How if the init.sql needs parameter, it's possible to pass parameter to the container to execute correctly the sql files ?

Answer (score 0):

You need an applications.properties suitable for [MySql](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/), something like:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

Then you can add a [data.sql](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) in your /src/test/resources which will automatically be run.

Comment: I don't get - how is that supposed to work ? spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto - will do the magic ? Will it create new tables and import data ? I've tried - nothing working.

Comment: @AlfredMoon once you have a database spring will look for the data.sql and run it. Work through the 2 examples.